# Use TAL:defined variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, plone, zope

I'm creating a page template for a plone-based website. I've defined some variables using the template attribute language:

```
<tal:macro metal:define-macro="sample" tal:define="var python: here.getThisVar();">
```

Now I would like to use `var` in an extern javascript file, that I call by clicking a button inside my template. How can I transfer my variable, that I can work with it in my javascript file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your template define a javascript variable by writing it out using TAL like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" tal:content="string:var MY_VAR=${view/myVar};"></script>
```

Now MY_VAR should be available in scope of your external js as long as you call it after the line above...

Answer (score 4):

Another way: inject your variable into HTML using an HTML 5 `data` attribute::

```
<div id="myVar" tal:attributes="data-myVar python:here.getThisVar();">
```

Then read it using JAvaScript/jQuery::

```
$('#myVar').data('myVar');
```

Comment: Thanks for your good answer! I'm sure it works, but unfortunately i have to work with an old plone system, which doesn't support HTML5. But I will keep it in mind for my next project :).

Comment: You can use HTML 5 even on old Plone, the only difference is in the jQuery version you have (can be 1.2 or 1.3).

Change change the JS to:

`jq('#myVar').attr('myVar');`

Comment: Sorry, can't edit my last comment. The real code is `jq('#myVar').attr('data-myVar');`

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of ways to do it. All involve constructing Javascript code as if it's text, then returning the result for insertion into a page or rendering as a JS resource in the javascript registry.

If you'd like a robust example that includes provisions for message translatability and works with the JS resource registry, see the way Plone itself does it: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/4.2.7/Products/CMFPlone/browser/jsvariables.py

Comment: I love the example straight from CMFPlone.  I think the consensus is using `tal:content` to define and set js variables, then adding static js code that uses those vars.   I personally create a namespace (js object) for this stuff to avoid collisions:  `tal:content="string:var Plone.myVar = 'foo'"`